# C# NetTopologySuite M-values

Tags: c#, .net-core, nettopologysuite

I'm using NetTopologySuite as a .net core replacement for SqlGeometries. It seems like it doesn't support M values in the points or coordinates although it has M properties. For example this simple code:

```
using NetTopologySuite.Geometries;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace PlaygroundCore
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var p3 = new Point(1, 2, 3);
            p3.Y = 8;
            p3.M = 1;
            var m = p3.M;

            Debug.WriteLine(p3);
            Debug.WriteLine(p3.M);
            Debug.WriteLine(m);
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
POINT (1 8 3)
NaN
NaN
```

The M value seems to be completely rejected. Is this a bug in the implementation? Is there any way of creating Points/Coordinates/LineStrings with M-values?

Answer (score 2):

The default coordinate sequence is `CoordinateArraySequence` which does not currently support `M` values, but it looks like `DotSpatialAffineCoordinateSequence` does support M values. To get `M` values working I had to do the following

```
using NetTopologySuite.Geometries;
using NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Implementation;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace NetTopologyTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //This sequence has to be initialized with ordinates XYZM. If you construct it
            //with just XYZ values, then you can't add M values to it later.
            var coordinateSequence = new DotSpatialAffineCoordinateSequence(new[] { 1.0, 2.0 }, new[] { 3.0 }, new[] { 4.0 });
            var sequenceFactory = new DotSpatialAffineCoordinateSequenceFactory(GeoAPI.Geometries.Ordinates.XYZM);
            var geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory(sequenceFactory);
            var p3 = new Point(coordinateSequence, geometryFactory);
            p3.Y = 8;
            p3.M = 1;
            var m = p3.M;

            Debug.WriteLine(p3);
            Debug.WriteLine(p3.M);
            Debug.WriteLine(m);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not a bug, It depends on what the coordinate sequence(factory) can handle. The (default) CooedinateSequence and irs factory can handle atm three, the third being Z.

Comment: Thanks TJ for an alternative solution. @FObermaier When implementing an interface (in this case IPoint) I'd consider it, if not a bug, at least bad/unwanted design to have a callable setter but not a getter for one of the interface properties. No matter what's under the hood, since this is what's publicly visible to the user.

Comment: @Johan, you'd prefer a `NotSupportedException`? I've seen plenty of public interfaces that have only been partially implemented.

Comment: @FObermaier I'd prefer a proper implementation. And when it's an official Microsoft .NET nuget package (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite) I expect it to work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a <s>bug</s> feature that is missing from the default implementation of `ICoordinateSequence`. It looks like they have started to make changes to support M values, but those changes have not been made everywhere. Below is at least one area where M values are not supported in the code that is ultimately causing the issue that you are seeing.

When referencing p3.M it is using these get and set methods.

```
    public double M
    {
        get
        {
            if (CoordinateSequence == null)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("M called on empty Point");
            return CoordinateSequence.GetOrdinate(0, Ordinate.M);
        }
        set => CoordinateSequence.SetOrdinate(0, Ordinate.M, value);
    }
```

Which then in turn calls `GetOrdinate` and `SetOrdinate` in `CoordinateArraySequence`

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the ordinate of a coordinate in this sequence.
    /// Ordinate indices 0 and 1 are assumed to be X and Y.
    /// Ordinate indices greater than 1 have user-defined semantics
    /// (for instance, they may contain other dimensions or measure values).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">The coordinate index in the sequence.</param>
    /// <param name="ordinate">The ordinate index in the coordinate (in range [0, dimension-1]).</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public double GetOrdinate(int index, Ordinate ordinate)
    {
        switch (ordinate)
        {
            case Ordinate.X:
                return Coordinates[index].X;
            case Ordinate.Y:
                return Coordinates[index].Y;
            case Ordinate.Z:
                return Coordinates[index].Z;
            default:
                return double.NaN;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the value for a given ordinate of a coordinate in this sequence.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">The coordinate index in the sequence.</param>
    /// <param name="ordinate">The ordinate index in the coordinate (in range [0, dimension-1]).</param>
    /// <param name="value">The new ordinate value.</param>
    public void SetOrdinate(int index, Ordinate ordinate, double value)
    {
        switch (ordinate)
        {
            case Ordinate.X:
                Coordinates[index].X = value;
                break;
            case Ordinate.Y:
                Coordinates[index].Y = value;
                break;
            case Ordinate.Z:
                Coordinates[index].Z = value;
                break;
            //default:
            //    //throw new ArgumentException("invalid ordinate index: " + ordinate);
        }
    }
```

Which, as you can see, when you call `SetOrdinate` with `Ordinate.M` nothing really gets set, and when calling `GetOrdinate` with `Ordinate.M` it will always return NaN.

If you are really wanting to use NetTopologySuite, you could fork the repo from here https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite and make the updates needed to support `M` values by default, but I imagine there are many things that would need to be changed. If you do update it I'm sure the guys maintaining the NetTopologySuite GitHub repo would appreciate a pull request with any of the changes.

Comment: Allright, that explains things. I may be wrong but isn't NetTopologySuite the only option to make it work with Entity Framework Core (i.e. to be able to fetch and save geometries from/to database)?